# PHP superclass and subclass

Tags: php, inheritance

A simple question, does the following make sense ?

**Class B extends Class A**

class A constructor:

```
function __construct(){
    //do something
}
```

Class B constructor:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Is there any significant advantage to implementing the child constructor at all in this case?

I can only think of :

- The entire code for class B will be more "complete" in structure

Would be interesting to know if there is any significant advantages in coding or in structuring etc.

Comment: If your class `A` has 100 defined methods which you want to use in your class `B`, do you "reimplement" all of them in class `B`...? :)

Comment: I think thats a question of flavor. For me it makes no sense. To keep consistency, you would have to do this for every method.

Comment: in this case, you dont need the constructor in class b, as the constructor of class a is used automaticly. but if you need to do something special in class b you need the call to parent to get the contructor of class a be also executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time you want to invoke your parent constructor from your subclass (child class) is when you want to add custom code in your constructor.

In your example you can leave out the __construct() method altogether in Class B.

However you might want to do something like this:

```
class A {

  function __construct() {
    run_a_function();
    $this->set = "a variable";
  }

}

class B {

  function __construct() {
    run_a_function_specific_to_class_b();
    $this->set = "a variable specific to class b";

    // now call the parent constructor
    parent::__construct();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. If all your constructor (or *any* method for that matter) does is call the `parent` method of the same name, then there's no advantage whatsoever. Just more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

A local constructor overrides its parent:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            // Your own constructor code
       }
}
?>
```

If you have a __construct() method in the child class you must call the parent constructor explicitly.

If you have no desire to run anything in the child constructor, do not specify the constructor method in the child and the parents constructor will be called automatically.