# PHP variable initiation in super class

Tags: php, oop

My question is concerning the inheritance mechanisms in object oriented PHP. If I want a class variable to be initialized in a super class in its constructor and all children classes to make use of initialized variable, I can't do this in the constructor of the superclass, since the superclasses constructor is not implicitly called by the children classes constructor, as in Java. If I have to manually call the super classes constructor from every children constructor, I do not have any benefit from simply doing the initialization in every children classes constructor.

How can I solve this problem? Any ideas?

```
class superclass {

  protected $a;

  function __construct() {
    $this->a = new Foo();
  }

}

class childrenclass1 extends superclass {

  function __construct() {
    do_something;
  }

  function childrenfunction() {
    $this->a->method(); // not initalized;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please demonstrate your scenario with proper code sample.

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428077/php-superclass-and-subclass

Comment: Not completely clear but if you init a variable in your constructor of super class and want to use it in the child class' constructor then you have to call the parent constructor like `parent::__construct()`..

Answer (score 2):

Like Java, the superclass constructor is only called automatically when the child classes don't implement their own constructor. Alternatively, the initial property values can be declared as part of the class definition if they're a constant expression.

So, basically, your choices are:

1. Initialize the variable with a non-dynamic value in the parent class:

   ```
   protected $var = 123;
   ```
2. Use `parent::__construct()` in all child classes that implement their own constructor. This is still better than initializing those properties in each child class, because using the parent's constructor doesn't duplicate code.

If the inheritance depth is 2 (i.e. only parent and child) you could drop the child constructor and define an initialization method:

```
class Parent
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        ...
        $this->initialize();
    }

    protected function initialize() {}
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    protected final function initialize()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but both examples won't work for me. 1. is not possible since the demanded init value is a new Object(). 2. is not possible since I dont see any benefit compared to initialization of the variable in each of the children classes. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Ferenjito From my personal experience, only C++ implements implicit constructor chaining; having said that, you still reap some benefits from doing `parent::__construct()`, because that way the code is not duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit to not doing the initialization in every child class constructor is that the logic of what to initialize it to can be kept in a single place - in the parent constructor. Calling the parent constructor from every child constructor can be tedious, but at least it's not duplicating the logic.

Your other option is to make the variable private, and use a method to access it from the child classes. The method can initialize it if needed, and then return the value.

```
class superclass {
    private $a;

    protected function getA() {
        if (!($this->a instanceof Foo)) {
            $this->a = new Foo();
        }
        return $this->a;
    }
}

class childrenclass1 extends superclass {

    public function childrenfunction() {
        $this->getA()->method();
    }
}
```

...don't forget to access your variable or method using `$this`. You can't leave that out in PHP like you can in Java.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to call parent constructor because it can initialize some variables or do other usefull things. But if you don't want to write in any child constructor parent::__construct() you can avoid write child constructor and move everything to a special method init. It will look like as:

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
        do smt
    } 
}

class B extends A {
    public function init() {
        do smt
    } 
}

$b = new B(); 
$b->init();
```

Comment: Or even have an empty init() in the parent class, and automatically call init() from the parent constructor.